# Redis: Common Redis for different servers but common drupal site

Tags: redis, drupal-7

We have two servers where same drupal site have installed (access the common database). Need to use the common redis for both servers (i.e. common site).

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply point the web servers (any number from 1 to n) to the same Redis instance, i.e. use the same value for `conf['redis_client_host']`. You'll also need a Redis server that can handle the traffic and data.